# Add a gradle repository to an expo app build with eas build / managed workflow

Tags: android, gradle, expo, eas

I have the following...

**Situation:**

I have a react native app (lets call it "MyApp") build on the expo platform. I use `eas build` to build the project.

Lately I forked the expo-camera package to update the iOS part to be able to use the ultra wide camera. For now I left the android part untouched. I uploaded my fork to the npm-registry as `myApp-expo-camera` and updated the dependency in MyApp from `expo-camera` to `myApp-expo-camera`

**Error:**

Now when I build iOS it all works as expected, but when I build android it tells me, that it is missing the `cameraview` package:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.android:cameraview:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :expo > project :expo-camera
```

**Problem:**

This `cameraview` package comes with the [`expo-camera`](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/main/packages/expo-camera/android/maven/com/google/android/cameraview/1.0.0) as an .aar archive. The [README.md](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/main/packages/expo-camera/README.md) in `expo-camera` says for the installation in a managed expo project to use `expo install expo-camera` which is no solution for me since I want to use my fork.

For the installation in a bare react native project it says to add the following to the `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {

        // * Your other repositories here *

        // * Add a new maven block after other repositories / blocks *
        maven {
            // expo-camera bundles a custom com.google.android:cameraview
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven"
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I understand I can use "none expo" third party react native packages since I'm using `eas build` but I can not add this to the `build.gradle` because I'm still in the managed workflow of expo (and therefor do not even have a `build.gradle` file).

**Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this situation?**

Sincerely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens, that I found the **solution** to my problem. So for everybody with a similar problem:

The `expo-camera` package has a file `withCamera.ts` in the plugin directory. This file contains logic, that writes the needed line of `build.gradle` code into the `build.gradle` of your actual / own project. But for this to work you need to run the forked `expo-camera` package in the prebuild section of the `eas build` workflow.
This can be achived by adding the following to the app.json / app.config.js in your own expo-project:

```js
plugins: ['myApp-expo-camera'],
```

With this line the `eas build` process knows, that your `myApp-expo-camera` needs to be prebuild.

Also make sure, that you have adjusted the packagename in the `withCamera.ts` file to your fork (e.g. `myApp-expo-camera`).

**What I still don't understand is:**
Why would you not need to do that for the original `expo-camera` package... but maybe expo has all their own packages already in a prebuild config... who knows!

Comment: You are the realest of real MVPs. Thank you Custo!